# Set Dependency Property Value in Event Trigger of XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I am trying to set the value for one of the dependency property in the Event Trigger. Unable to achieve this in Styles.

The below mentioned style in the code is for my DataGridCell, so when some Drop event occurs on the DataGridCell i would like to set the property value to **True** for depedency property "dragdrop:DragDropHelper.HighlightColumn".

I would need some thing like below.

```
<Style x:Key="GridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"></Setter>                    
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Drop">
            <Setter Property="dragdrop:DragDropHelper.HighlightColumn" Value="True"></Setter>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a Setter to an EventTrigger. Use an appropriate `BeginStoryboard` action like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Drop">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(dragdrop:DragDropHelper.HighlightColumn)">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Comment: i have tried the above approach. but getting exception..    "Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'dragdrop:DragDropHelper.HighlightColumn'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."

Comment: did you tried just Storyboard.TargetProperty="HighlightColumn" ?

Comment: Forgot to put the property name in parentheses, which is necessary for attached properties in [property paths for animation targets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms742451(v=vs.100).aspx#databinding_sa).